# fill input type range with slider in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build and input type `range` that when is growing the thumb to the right side the track is filled with a new color.

in the past I used to do this with the plain vanilla JS and CSS.

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
  }

  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  input[type="range"]:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: transparent;
    color: transparent;
  }

  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: var(--strongCyan);
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: -10px 5px 50px var(--strongCyan);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    margin-top: -14px;
  }

  input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8.4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: var(--lightGrayishBlueEmptySideBar);
    border-radius: 70px;
  }
}
```

but now with react this is the result:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-waterfall-i1w5g)

In the beginning I thought that maybe was the box shadow but when I changed it nothing happen.

Comment: You can try: https://codepen.io/raeesh/pen/VwKQQKd   
or https://codepen.io/raeesh/pen/jpGaYd